# How to Connect an Oracle DB to Asp.net C# and save the data in data set?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, reporting-services

I have a reporting tool project which have filtering therefore I would like to save the query in a string based on the filter and fill the data set then I will bind it with a grid view.
my question is, how to Connect an Oracle DB to Asp.net C# and save the data in data set?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance google Oracle + ASP.NET? If you did then you will find plenty of samples which demonstrate step by step what to do:
[Connecting to Oracle or Access from ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20056/Connecting-to-Oracle-or-Access-from-ASP-NET)